# Wordpress how to apply specific CSS property based on user role on every page

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

I am using the theme "Neve".

I have added a custom function to `my child's theme > functions.php`

Based on the user role, if the user is X role the topbar which appears above the head/nav menu will change colour.

Can someone advise where I may have gone wrong / as to why this is not changing colour when expected to do so?

Kind Regards,

```
function topbar_switcher () {
    
    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
    
    switch (true)  {
    case ( user_can( $current_user, "subscriber") ):
        ?>
            <style> 
                .header-top {
                background-color:black;
                }
            </style>
        <?php
    break;
 case ( user_can( $current_user, "customer") ):
        ?>
            <style> 
                .header-top {
                    background-color:#00337f;
                }
            </style>
        <?php
    break;
 case ( user_can( $current_user, "administrator") ):
    ?>
            <style> 
                .header-top {
                    background-color:yellow;
                }
            </style>
        <?php
 break;
            
    }   
}
```

Top bar is the red strip where you see the phone icon:

[image]

Comment: You should not add extra styles in the code. Do this all in CSS. Then give it a classname and use that in code.

Comment: @MarkusZeller Sorry I am new to wordpress and custom functions etc, what do you mean sorry? .header-top { already exists in my css stylesheet

Comment: Add three custom css styles like `.header-top.subscriber { color: green}`,  `.header-top.customer{ color: blue}`, etc. Then in your code use the appropriate template file and use `$color = 'subscriber';` ... `<div class="header-top $color">`;

Comment: Hi @MarkusZeller I am struggling to locate the appropriate template file (Neve is the template) for the top-bar element. Can you possibly suggest an alternative method to achieve what I need, thanks

Comment: @richag By *"topbar which appears above the head/nav menu"*, do you mean the wordpress admin bar?

Comment: @Ruvee I am using the theme Neve, which has a top bar that appears above the main site header (logo, menu etc) not the admin area. This top bar is enabled via appearance > customise , .header-top is the property that has background-colour ,

Comment: @Ruvee, i have added an image to my question to show you what I am referring to as “top bar” the code used above was slightly modified and i create a shortcode with XYZ snippets and when applying a shortcode to one of the pages, the top bar changed colour based on user role, I need this to apply to all pages without having to use shortcode

Comment: @Ruvee, that is correct the top bar has the class .header-top

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> *"I need this to apply to all pages without having to use shortcode"*

You could use the `wp_head` action hook to run the following code for every single page without using a shortcode.

```php
add_action('wp_head', 'changing_color_of_top_navbar');

function changing_color_of_top_navbar()
{

    $current_user = wp_get_current_user();

    $user_roles = $current_user->roles;

    if (in_array("subscriber", $user_roles)) {
        ?>
        <style>
            .header-top {
                background-color: black;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
    } elseif (in_array("customer", $user_roles)) {
    ?>
        <style>
            .header-top {
                background-color: #00337f;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
    } elseif (in_array("administrator", $user_roles)) {
    ?>
        <style>
            .header-top {
                background-color: yellow;
            }
        </style>
    <?php
    }
}
```

Code goes into the `functions.php` file of your active theme or child theme.

Comment: works perfectly, thank you!